# What does "If it were not for the fact that I never speak ill of my colleague" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "I see," said Professor McGonagall, fixing Harry with her beady eyes. "Then you should know, Potter, that Sybill Trelawney has predicted the death of one student a year since she arrived at this school. None of them has died  yet. Seeing death omens is her favorite way of greeting a new class. **If it were not for the fact that I never speak ill of my colleague --**
>
> Professor McGonagall broke  off, ...

I don't quite understand the sentence above in bold. What does it try to convey? Particularly the part: *If it were not for the fact*

-- From Harry Potter.

Comment: I think that's kind of humor! I mean he already talked shit behind her!

Comment: @Cardinal Yeah, that's the part that confuses me too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think the answer lays in the relationship between Trelawney and McGonagall.

In her E-book, *Short Stories From Hogwarts Of Heroism, Hardship, and Dangerous Hobbies*, J.K. Rowling discusses Trelawney in-depth, and **even gives some detail about the lukewarm relationship between Trelawney and McGonagall**. The author considers them "polar opposites", and of course Potter prefers Professor McGonagall.

So here by "If it were not for the fact that I never speak ill of my colleague", I think Professor McGonagall tried to tell Harry: 
1.It's not good to speak ill of your colleague but Trelawney is a little bit too grandiose(**for the fact**); 2.Don't be scared of her prediction.

Despite their differences, however, McGonagall leapt to Trelawney's defence because she sensed Trelawney's "underlying feeling of inadequacy". That's why we love Professor McGonagall, she's really upright.

[image]

Comment: So， can we paraphrase the sentence as: *it was the fact(Trelawney's behavior or talking) that made me to speak ill of Trelawney, but normally I don't speak ill of my colleague*? Is the paraphrase correct?

Comment: I think you're right.

Comment: I feel "the fact" here should refer to "*I never speak ill of my colleague*". I found another example on the web: "*If it weren't for the fact that he gave them money, the organization would be bankrupt*". There, the fact is "he gave them money". So, now I think "*If it were not for the fact that I never speak ill of my colleague*" looks an incomplete sentence. What do you think?

Comment: @dan It is an incomplete sentence. That's why it ends with a dash. She didn't finish it *because* she doesn't speak ill of her colleague. To speak ill of her, the rest of the sentence could be something like *I'd say she doesn't know what she's talking about* or *I'd say she's too melodramatic*.

Comment: @dan You know what, I think I've got it wrong. You are right, the "fact" here should be "I never speak ill of my college", because there is a "that". So I think like Jason said, the incomplete sentence means that "I really want to say that Trelawney doesn't know what she's talking, but no, I would never do something like that."